# Spring 3.2 MVC -- HTTP Status 405 Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring-mvc, http-status

I'm getting a 405 error from my Spring 3.2 MVC form.  It's telling me POST is not supported, but both my form and controller method use it.  Here is the relevant portion of my form.

```
<form:form commandName="bulletin" method="post" value="/processBulletin">
```

Here is the relevant portion of my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/processBulletin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processBulletin(
            @ModelAttribute("bulletin") Bulletin bulletin, Model model,
            BindingResult result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify an `action` in the form so it's likely trying to post to the same URL on which the form is rendered.

The [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.form) makes no mention of a `value` attribute.

In your `form` change `value` to `action` and see if that does the trick for you.